# Javascript images cover the full page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below code that is a function for changing background-image every 10th second:

```
$(function() {
var body = $(".home");
var backgrounds = [
    "url(img/Agure.jpg)",
    "url(img/Arsenal1.jpg)",
    "url(img/ManUtd.jpg)",
    "url(img/stadion.jpg)",
];
var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
        "background",
        backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
body.css("background", backgrounds[0]);
```

The code works but I want the images always to cover the full page. Some images are to small to cover the full page so they just stack up next to each other. Any suggestions how I can change the code?

HTML and CSS:

```
<section class="home">
    <div class="centered">
        <div class="h-100 row align-items-center">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

.home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Out of my curiosity, why are you using JS for this task when a CSS animation would be a better choice?

Comment: I have no good answer. Im not very skilled in css yet..

Comment: By using `body.css("background", …` you are overwriting all other `background` properties with their defaults here … You should only set the background image there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is a combination of two things:

- You aren't using `background-repeat: no-repeat` which means the images will tile to cover the background (This is only visible when the image is smaller than the container, which can be confusing)
- And you're setting `background` in JS, rather than `background-image` which would overwrite your extra CSS properties.

Here's a modified version:

```js
$(function() {
  var body = $(".home");
  var backgrounds = [
    "url(https://picsum.photos/200/300)",
    "url(https://picsum.photos/100/300)",
    "url(https://picsum.photos/300/300)",
    "url(https://picsum.photos/250/300)",
  ];
  var current = 0;

  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      "background-image",
      backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
    );
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
  }
  setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
  body.css("background-image", backgrounds[0]);
})
```

```css
.home {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="home">
  <div class="centered">
    <div class="h-100 row align-items-center">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

When the image is small the browser automatically adds multiple image (stacked in your case)

Try adding the following in your css to avoid it

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Also instead of writing

```
body.css("background", backgrounds[0]);
```

write

```
body.css("background-image", backgrounds[0]);
```